# Grass toolbar for QGIS 2.10

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I don't see the GRASS toolbar in QGIS 2.10 (Pisa). There are still GRASS commands in the Processing toolbox. I know there was some upgrade of GRASS for 2.10. Is the toolbar not available anymore? If so, how would you make a mapset, etc?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The 2.10 program group has an option to open QGIS with GRASS. This is different than previous versions. 2.10 also has the QT Designer so you can make your own widgets. Very progressive!

Answer (score 2):

In 2.10.1 I'm able to access GRASS Tools panel, and GRASS toolbar by:

1. Enabling GRASS plugin
2. Go to Menu Bar / View / Panels and confirm GRASS Tools is checked
3. Go to Menu Bar / View / Toolbars and confirm GRASS is checked

Then, I'm able to click the 'New Mapset' button in the GRASS Toolbar.

Comment: I don't have GRASS in my plugins. I downloaded the standalone 32 bit for Windows. Did you install from the OSGeo4W installer?

Comment: I'm on a Mac and installed the version provided by [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com).  When I went to 'Manage and Install Plugins...' option in the Menu Bar, GRASS was already there.  I just had to check the box to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows you have a "special version" of QGIS with GRASS available:
[image]

Start this special version and enable the now available grass-plugin:
[image]

Go to Menu Bar / View / Panels and check, that its enabled (should be already by default)
Go to Menu Bar / View / Toolbars and check, that its enabled (should be already by default)

Answer (score 2):

Have you enabled the advance interface :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this page for the development progress: http://www.gissula.eu/qgis-grass-plugin-crowdfunding/progress.html

I assume you use QGIS 2.10 with GRASS 7. The site above states that mapset management will be implemented for QGIS 2.12, whereas in QGIS 2.10

> GRASS plugin browser and add layer tools removed, substituted by standard QGIS browser.

I.e. at the moment you can use the QGIS browser to add, rename, move GRASS layers and you can even import layers just by drag and drop (watch the video).